# Maintaining date format when using pandas.rpy.common.load_data() to import R dataframe

Tags: python, r, pandas

I've loaded a R dataframe (myRData) into pandas using pandas.rpy.common.load_data() as follows:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
import pandas.rpy.common as com
print robjects.r.load(".RData")
myRData = com.load_data('myRData')
```

However, the majority of variables (including dates) are imported as float64. So, for example, the date 2005-04-26 in R is imported as 12899 (i.e. the number of days since 1970-01-01) in pandas dataframe. Can anyone suggest how I can ensure date variables in the R dataframe are imported as a date format in the pandas dataframe?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([12899])

print df

       0
0  12899

df[0] = pd.to_datetime(df[0],  unit='d')

print df

           0
0 2005-04-26
```

Comment: Thanks for rapid reply. That's the answer I was looking for. Unfortunately, I don't have sufficient reputation to Vote Up your answer.